# How to guarantee that the slot will never be used in solidity?

Tags: constants, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

In some contracts, I see they use constant slot numbers. But how are they guaranteeing that that slot will never be used? For example in EIP1967 there is a slot for implementation:

```
// bytes32(uint256(keccak256("eip1967.proxy.implementation")) - 1)
_IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT = 0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc;
```

and another example is in the Gnosis's contract:

```
// keccak256("fallback_manager.handler.address")
FALLBACK_HANDLER_STORAGE_SLOT = 0x6c9a6c4a39284e37ed1cf53d337577d14212a4870fb976a4366c693b939918d5;
```

The question is: Is it safe to use any slot using this approach? Can some dynamic array or mapping be used in this slot? For example:

```
// keccak256("some.dummy.address.address")
SOME_SLOT = 0x47bd68279a41c9ae1cc277c8922809c3c82881c5143963fcfc95b91a61097eb5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum writes to the free memory slots. Fromt the docs:

> Solidity always places new objects at the free memory pointer and
> memory is never freed (this might change in the future).

if you already wrote into a slot, Ethereum will not store anything in that slot. Now it is up to developers to keep track of which slots they already have used. In order to define which slots they are going to use, developers use inline assembly. (This is one of the advantages of inline assembly. It gives you granular control over the memory)

Comment: I think that doc is talking about memory but not storage.